# How to set margins, header and footer with fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

This is a document template with header and footer, but I have no idea how to make a broken line and that the header look like this (all at the top is the header)

Someone can help me?

[image]

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) as this is not a `please-do-this-for-me` service, what have you tried so far? Questions like this with no code or attempts will often get flagged with poor quality, or unclear what you are asking.

Comment: i dont know how to set this double line in header and how to set this dashed line i spend days on that. i  dont even know 
how to approach it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how elegant this works, but you can try fake-underlining.
You need to include: 
`\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % [normalem] prevents the package from changing the default behavior of \emph to underline.`

then `\dasheduline{\hfill}` should work. `\hfill` can be replaced with an element you want to underline. 
The rest should be easy to arrange.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: thank you for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[headheight=80pt, includehead]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newbox\dashbox\setbox\dashbox\hbox{-\,}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\makebox[\headwidth][c]{\xleaders\copy\dashbox\hfill}}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\headrule}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\sffamily
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
    City \\
    Street \\
    something
  \end{tabular}
  \hspace{2cm}
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
    City \\
    Street \\
    something
  \end{tabular}\\[-1ex]%
  \headrule\\
  {\footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
      tele and other info\hspace{3cm} 666 666 66 641 123 675\\
      something aaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccc
    \end{tabular}%
  }
}
\fancyfoot[C]{tralala tralala tralala tralala }

\begin{document}

\kant[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]